# FileUploader plugin (PhoneGap) for iPhone

Tags: iphone, cordova, file-upload

I am trying to use the [PhoneGap FileUploader plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/FileUploader) to upload an image from iPhone to my server

How do I use the `uploadByUri` function exactly? I don't understand all the parameters...

```
FileUploader.prototype.uploadByUri("http://www.mysite.com/images/", imageURI,
params, fileKey, "myimage", "image/jpg", uploadSuccess, uploadFail, uploadProgress)
```

What do I use for for "`params`" and "`filekey`"? The read-me file says:

> - fileKey Parameter name of the file
> - params Object with key: value params to send to the server

Right now I am putting `null` and get no errors, but there is no image in my destination folder.

Also, do you know if I can upload directly an image in base64-encoded string from the camera rather than an image from the album?

Thank you for your help.

Roberto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fileKey is the name of the file field that the server is expecting. So if you were uploading a file via a web app you would have an `<input type="file" name="fileKey">` and the server would be looking for the "fileKey" to get the file data.

Params is unused I believe.

Uploading a base64 encoded image would be just like uploading a text file I assume. On the server you would need to convert it to an image file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think there is a word missing: "you would have an and the server would". And I still do not understand what the fileKey is about. What field is the server expecting? I am already specifying a destination file name ('myimage') and the source file (imageURI)...

Comment: ha I put in some html in my answer and it removed it! in the HTML page you would have an input element with type="file" and name="fileKey" attributes. So your server code would expect a POST message with the file data identified by the "fileKey" name attribute if it was being posted from a regular web page.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it took me 3 days to figure out that FileUploader was not doing ftp uploads, and that the server destination was actually not a folder but a server-side script. I am going to answer my question in case someone else needs help.

Here is a barebone php script to save the image 'uploaded' by FileUploaded.

```
<? 
// the actual uploaded image 
$uploaded_image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']; 
// the uploaded image name 
$uploaded_image_name = $_FILES['image']['name']; 
// location where you want to save the image 
$saved_image = "my_images/$uploaded_image_name"; 
// saves the image 
move_uploaded_file($uploaded_image, $saved_image); 
?>
```

Make sure to create a folder where your php file is ("my_images" in this example).

To trigger the FileUploader plugin:

```
window.plugins.FileUploader.uploadByUri("http://www.yourserver.com/your_php_script.php", your_actual_image, null, "image", "my_image.jpg", "image/jpg", uploadSuccess, uploadFail, uploadProgress);
```

Notice that my fileKey parameter is "image" because I am uploading an image. This matches `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']` and `$_FILES['image']['name']`.

Make sure to copy 'fileUploader.js' in your www folder, but 'fileUploader.h' and 'fileUploader.m' in your Plugins folder. (Do not copy the FileUploader folder itself).

Roberto

Answer (score 1):

Just to update. Phonegap now has a file api, which seems to do what the filuploader plugin does: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html